# Why does my Int value of an int array become 0 when it is higher than 10?

Tags: java, arrays, windows, integer, logic

I wrote code which sorts the values of two arrays in ascending order and it actually works but only if I use values lower than 10 in the arrays. It actually sounds like a simple problem, but I already tried anything and I just don't understand why it isn't working.

First I should show you the merge function I wrote:

```
public static int[] merge(int[] leftArray, int[] rightArray){
    int[] result = new int[leftArray.length + rightArray.length];
    int position = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;

    String result_debug;
    while(true){
        /*
        System.out.println("Result: " + result[position]);
        System.out.println("Left: " + leftArray[left]);
        System.out.println("Right: " + rightArray[right]);
         */
        if(leftArray[left] < rightArray[right]){
            result[position] = leftArray[left];

            position = position + 1;
            result_debug = arrayToString(result);
            System.out.println(result_debug);
            left++;
        } else if (leftArray[left] > rightArray[right]) {
            result[position] = rightArray[right];
            position = position + 1;
            result_debug = arrayToString(result);
            System.out.println(result_debug);
            right++;

        } else if (leftArray[left] == rightArray[right]) {
            result[position] = leftArray[left];
            result_debug = arrayToString(result);
            System.out.println(result_debug);
            position = position + 1;
            left++;
            result[position] = rightArray[right];
            result_debug = arrayToString(result);
            System.out.println(result_debug);
            position = position + 1;
            right++;
        }

        if(left == leftArray.length && right < rightArray.length) {

            for(int i = position; i < rightArray.length; i++){
                result[i] = rightArray[right];
                System.out.println(rightArray[right]);
                right++;
            }
            break;
        } else if (right == rightArray.length && left < leftArray.length) {

            for(int i = position; i < leftArray.length; i++){
                result[i] = leftArray[left];
                System.out.println(leftArray[left]);
                left++;
            }
            break;
        } else if (left == leftArray.length && right == rightArray.length) {

            break;


        }

        //System.out.println("Result: " + result[position]);
        //System.out.println("Left: " + leftArray[left]);
        //System.out.println("Right: " + rightArray[right]);
    }


    System.out.println("Result: " + result[result.length - 1]);
    
    return result;
}
```

Anytime I use arrays with values below 10, it works just perfectly, but when I use anything higher it becomes 0. As you can see I already tried some debugging methods but without success. I also wrote a function to make an int array into a String to print it out I can show you that function too:

```
public static String arrayToString(int[]arr){
    String result = "[" + arr[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        result = result + ", " + arr[i];
    }
    result += "]";
    return result;
}
```

I also thought it could be because of the arraytoString method, but as you can see at the bottom of my merge method, I already checked that and the output is still 0, so it isn't because of that.

I don't think that it is a logic problem because as I said as long as I use values below 10 it works and also, at the beginning when I programmed it, it didn't even work with values higher than 8 it later began to work with 9 and 10.

I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: what happens when you put value higher than 10 in array? do you get error ? wrong result?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Nothing at all it just stays zero. -> Wrong result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is not with array values, but rather with the placement of values in the two arrays. the problem will be manifested with the input

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3};
    int[] b = {4,5,6};
    int[] c = merge(a, b);
```

you should learn how to use debugger. then you can debug your code properly. The problem is that the first item in array b is larger than all items in array a. so you populate result with all items from a and advance `left` (and also `position`) until `left` is equal to `leftArray.length`.

in the above example, at this point, both `left` and `position` are equal 3 .

at that point you enter this if statement:
`if(left == leftArray.length && right < rightArray.length) {`
you assign `i` to start with value `position`. making it equal to `rightArray.length` and thus you do not copy over array b.

Comment: But I thought I did that... in my if statement `if(left == leftArray.length && right < rightArray.length)` I set i as position and let it fill the rest of the array position... or do you mean something else? I am sorry if I missunderstood you I am from germany and my english skills aren't bad but also not very good...

Comment: I totally forgot to mention: the int[] arrays  leftArray and rightArray have to be in an ascending order anyways

Comment: the arrays in the example are ordered. maybe you can provide example of valid input

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but I just solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what exactly was the point which solved it but after some experimenting my Code runs as it should just the last value of the result array had to be placed outside the loop. The working Code is:

```
   public static int[] merge(int[] leftArray, int[] rightArray){
    int[] result = new int[leftArray.length + rightArray.length];
    int position = 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;

    String result_debug;
    while(true){
        /*
        System.out.println("Result: " + result[position]);
        System.out.println("Left: " + leftArray[left]);
        System.out.println("Right: " + rightArray[right]);
         */
        if(leftArray[left] < rightArray[right]){
            result[position] = leftArray[left];

            position = position + 1;
            result_debug = arrayToString(result);
            System.out.println(result_debug);
            left++;
        } else if (leftArray[left] > rightArray[right]) {
            result[position] = rightArray[right];
            position = position + 1;
            result_debug = arrayToString(result);
            System.out.println(result_debug);
            right++;

        } else if (leftArray[left] == rightArray[right]) {
            result[position] = leftArray[left];
            result_debug = arrayToString(result);
            System.out.println(result_debug);
            position = position + 1;
            left++;
            result[position] = rightArray[right];
            result_debug = arrayToString(result);
            System.out.println(result_debug);
            position = position + 1;
            right++;
        }

        if(left == leftArray.length && right < rightArray.length) {

            for(int i = position; right < rightArray.length; i++){
                result[i] = rightArray[right];
                System.out.println(rightArray[right]);
                right++;
            }
            break;
        } else if (right == rightArray.length && left < leftArray.length) {

            for(int i = position; left < leftArray.length; i++){
                result[i] = leftArray[left];
                System.out.println(leftArray[left]);
                left++;
            }
            break;
        } else if (left == leftArray.length && right == rightArray.length) {

            break;


        }

        //System.out.println("Result: " + result[position]);
        //System.out.println("Left: " + leftArray[left]);
        //System.out.println("Right: " + rightArray[right]);
    }


    System.out.println("Result: " + result[result.length - 1]);
    if(leftArray[leftArray.length - 1] > rightArray[rightArray.length - 1]){
        result[result.length - 1] = leftArray[leftArray.length - 1];
    }
    if(rightArray[rightArray.length - 1] > leftArray[leftArray.length - 1]){
        result[result.length - 1] = rightArray[rightArray.length - 1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: still not working correctly with input `{1,2,3}` and `{4,5,6}`

Comment: But why???????????? it worked with so many number why does it not work with these???

Comment: the solution does not work if all items in one array are smaller than all items in the other. the reason is specified in my solution.

Comment: I found my bug... it is so simple... in the for loops of my if statements `right == rightArray.length && left < leftArray.length` and the statement `left == leftArray.length && right < rightArray.length` I had `int i = position; i < leftArray.length; i++` BUT the value of position can be higher than the length of the array leftArray and rightArray.

Comment: I just corrected it in here now it works :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you don't have to use a custom function:

```
int[] one = new int[]{59, 1, 523, -43, 123, 5};
int[] two = new int[]{3, 901, 73, -4783, 1, 53};

//merging the arrays
int[] merged = new int[one.length + two.length];
System.arraycopy(one, 0, merged, 0, one.length);
System.arraycopy(two, 0, merged, one.length, two.length);

Arrays.sort(merged);

System.out.println(arrayToString(merged));
```

Output:
[-4783, -43, 1, 1, 3, 5, 53, 59, 73, 123, 523, 901]

Comment: It acutally is an assignment and also I used my own algorythm for that but thank you for the tip I will look how they wrote the function maybe it will help